# Performance analysis of pyspark filtering code

Tags: python, pyspark

This code is my edit of "Summary Statistics" at https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-statistics.html  . Specifically I'm filtering a mix of String and float values using `pDataI = mat.zipWithIndex().filter(lambda x: x[1] > 0).map(lambda x: x[0])`

Breaking this down :

```
mat.zipWithIndex() is O(sizeOf mat)
filter(lambda x: x[1] > 0) is O(sizeOf mat)
map(lambda x: x[0]) is O(sizeOf mat)
```

I seem to be performing alot of computations to just remove the first line from 
collection.

Entire code :

```
import numpy as np
from pyspark.mllib.stat import Statistics

data = []

data.append('c1,c2,c3')
data.append(np.array([1.0, 10.0, 100.0]))
data.append(np.array([2.0, 20.0, 200.0]))
data.append(np.array([3.0, 30.0, 300.0]))

mat = sc.parallelize(
    data
)  # an RDD of Vectors

pDataI = mat.zipWithIndex().filter(lambda x: x[1] > 0).map(lambda x: x[0])
summary = Statistics.colStats(pDataI)

print(summary.mean())  # a dense vector containing the mean value for each column
print(summary.variance())  # column-wise variance
print(summary.numNonzeros())  # number of nonzeros in each column

print pDataI.stats();
```

prints :

```
[   2.   20.  200.]

[  1.00000000e+00   1.00000000e+02   1.00000000e+04]

[ 3.  3.  3.]

(count: 3, mean: [   2.   20.  200.], stdev: [  0.81649658   8.16496581  81.64965809], max: [   3.   30.  300.], min: [   1.   10.  100.])
```

Can this be improved upon to just process the `mat` collection in a single pass ?

Comment: Why not just use `pyspark.DataFrame`?

Comment: @Grr how to convert mat to pyspark.DataFrame ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my money DataFrames are always a better solution that RDD's. I will assume that in a real working environment your data are stored in some kind of file or collection or whatever (csv, parquet, json, etc). Let's assume a csv for now. In this case you would just do the following:

```
df = sqlContext.read.csv('filename.csv', header=True)
```

From there you can get summary statistics with `df.describe()`.

[Here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrameReader) is the documentation for the DataFrameReader including all of the filetypes and collections you can read in.